# Knifing outside a chef run from a node

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, knife

I have a Jenkins server that I want to deploy some code to some servers. To pick the right servers, I would like the jenkins job to query chef for nodes with a particular role.

However, I am not sure if that is a good idea or an anti-pattern, and I am not sure how to go about it in practice.

The jenkins server is already listed as a non-admin client, so I am wondering if I can use the existing credentials for something or if I should create a jenkins admin and set up a `knife.rb` in Jenkins home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably want to use one of the Chef scripting libraries like chef-api (Ruby), PyChef (Python), or Jclouds (Java) rather than knife itself. Using Jenkins for deploys is a bit wonky as it isn't reeeeally meant for that, but you can make it work. Tools like Push Jobs, Fabric, and RunDeck are possibly better suited, and all have direct integration with Chef's node catalog like you describe.